# After update from XCode 4.5 DP4 to XCode 4.5, app runs on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I'm a newbie, so forgive me if I've included too much (or too little) information.  I tried deleting the derived data and restarting XCode, which was a suggestion I saw on another question similar to this one, but I still get the same three error messages:

Apple Mach-O Linker Error: linker command failed with exit code 1

```
Ld /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Intermediates/GayHaiku.build/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/GayHaiku normal armv7s
cd /Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku/facebook-ios-sdk/build/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Objects-normal/armv6 -L/Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku/facebook-ios-sdk/build/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Objects-normal/armv7 -L/Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku/facebook-ios-sdk/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku/facebook-ios-sdk/build/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku/facebook-ios-sdk/lib/facebook-ios-sdk -F/Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Intermediates/GayHaiku.build/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/GayHaiku.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework CFNetwork -lsqlite3 -lz.1.1.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AudioToolbox -framework Twitter -framework QuartzCore -framework MessageUI -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework Parse -o /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Intermediates/GayHaiku.build/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/GayHaiku

ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku/Parse.framework/Parse for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Uncategorized: command failed with exit code 1

```
CreateUniversalBinary /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.app/GayHaiku normal "armv7 armv7s"
cd /Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
lipo -create /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Intermediates/GayHaiku.build/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GayHaiku /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Intermediates/GayHaiku.build/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/GayHaiku -output /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.app/GayHaiku

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Intermediates/GayHaiku.build/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/GayHaiku (No such file or directory)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1
```

Dysmutil error:  unable to open executable

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.app.dSYM /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.app/GayHaiku
cd /Users/joel/Desktop/GayHaiku
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.app/GayHaiku -o /Users/joel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GayHaiku-crhnnbsqptnxaogjezyomdzplbag/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GayHaiku.app.dSYM
```

Any thoughts about how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have discovered a similar issue in one of my apps.

Are you linking against an external library that has not been compiled for armv7s? If so, you will get this error. To fix the problem, you either need to find the library and compile it with armv7s support, or you can remove armv7s from your valid architectures.

Do this by clicking on the project file, selecting you target, and deleting the armv7s line from the valid architectures line.

This worked for me.

Comment: You are a prince among men (or a princess among women)!  Now my question, though -- there doesn't seem to be a line that's only armv7s in valid architectures.  I'll post a photo in another answer.

Comment: Never mind -- I downloaded the latest version of the external library, and that fixed it!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!